# How to change a parent component's varibale from a child component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular. I'm trying to access/mutate a variable of a parent component from the child component. I've drawn a small diagram to explain my structure.

1. Label 1: the parent component where the variable (to be mutated) is situated.
2. Label 2: the child component which will change parent's variable on click event.
3. Label 3: the button inside child which will trigger the change.

[image]

I have checked many solutions like:

1. [Change parent component state from child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562884/change-parent-component-state-from-child-component)
2. [Angular access parent variable from child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071627/angular-access-parent-variable-from-child-component)
3. [Angular2: child component access parent class variable/function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201016/angular2-child-component-access-parent-class-variable-function)

But I'm not able to solve my problem. I've created an [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1fsxbq) also. Please have a look at my code.

**timeselector.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MonthpickerComponent } from '../monthpicker/monthpicker.component';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class TimeselectorComponent {

    x : boolean=false;

    @ViewChild('primaryMonthPicker', {static: false}) primaryMonthPicker: MonthpickerComponent;

    recievedFromChild:string="Intentionally left blank";

    GetOutputVal($event) {
        this.recievedFromChild=$event;
    }
}
```

**monthpicker.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class MonthpickerComponent {

  @Output() outputToParent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() {}

  sendToParent(string:string) {
    this.outputToParent.emit(string);
  }

  buttonClicked() {
    // some logic to access and change timeselector's x
    console.log("Change handler called");
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

My actual problem is way more complex than this. But I tried to reproduce the same. I just want to see the logic of how it is done, then I'll handle the things my way. I want to change the value of `x` to `true`.

An expert told me to create a service. But the project is very complex and I can't make changes to it. It's a team project. Is there any quick fix or less painful solution. Please correct me I'm completely blocked because of this. Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1fsxbq).

Comment: for your code you have to call `emit` function in your child to get the value emitted from child to parent in the parent ts file , **for example:** in your code you need to call this line `this.outputToParent.emit(string)` inside the click function `buttonClicked()` which called in every click on the button in child template

Comment: try this `buttonClicked() {this.sendToParent("string sent from child component");}`

Comment: I think you forgot to call the sendToParent function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k6fnfk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmonthpicker%2Fmonthpicker.component.html

You have to pass `x` to child component, like below:

```
<app-monthpicker [x]="x" (outputToParent)="GetOutputVal($event)"></app-monthpicker>
```

Then in your monthpicker (child) component:

```
  @Input() x;
```

And to change the `x` value:

```
 sendToParent() {
    let newX = this.x + 1;
    this.outputToParent.emit(newX);
  }
```

Comment: I'll quickly give this a try. Please give me 5 mins.

Comment: This is working perfectly. But Sir I'm sorry I made a mistake while framing the question. The variable in real scenario is a `boolean` type which is by default `false`. Can you tell me how to set it to `true` via same mechanism.

Comment: @Tanzeel sure, check this out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m6stf7?file=src/app/timeselector/timeselector.component.ts

Comment: I've changed my question also. Let me try your new solution. thanks :-)

Comment: Oh. Now I realized. I already have a `sendToParent` in my code. Which is like this:

    `sendToParent(string: string) {
        this.outputToParent.emit(string);
    }`

Comment: I tried to accommodate the new boolean value `this.outputToParent.emit(string, newX);` but I'm getting error that only 0-1 args are accepted. what should i do now. :-(

Comment: Sir, It is already there in the question. See code for **monthpicker.component.ts**

Comment: Ok, so check out my example based on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m6stf7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmonthpicker%2Fmonthpicker.component.ts

Comment: Sir I tried one more approach. I've posted an alternative answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

On button click(OR any event), you need to emit the value to the parent component using Output decorator.

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

I edited your slackblitz, as you were not emiting the output on button click, now it works fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zhpbr8

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. In fact I'm reading the links you shared. I appreciate everyone's help. :-)

Comment: I was asking to whom so ever did. Glad to help.

Comment: But my case is different. My `this.outputToParent.emit(string);` is already emitting some string after some logic. Can you please suggest some other way.

Comment: Is there any other way that I can hit that particular value of parent component.

Comment: You don't have to emit a string, you can emit an object as well. 
  @Output() outputToParent = new EventEmitter<{x: number, y: string}>();
Instead of providing a type here. It's better to create an Interface.

Comment: Ok. And then how to emit this object? Something like this? `sendToParent(string: string) {
        this.outputToParent.emit({});
    }`

Answer (score 1):

I've already got my answer. But I tried one more approach. I thought of it by myself. Please tell me to remove this if it is wrong.

**Logic**: Instead of hitting the value in parent component directly or using `sendToparent` and `this.outputToParent.emit(string);`. I created a custom mutator function in the parent component itself which will then change the state of the variable. And I'm simply calling that method from child component.

I took help from:

[Angular : calling parent component function from child component](https://medium.com/@sohailnazar4/angular-calling-parent-component-function-from-child-component-5dcccdc771d9)

Here's my code:

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-child (parentFun)="parentFun()"></app-child>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
x : boolean=false;
...
parentFun(){
  this.x=true;
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<button (click)="buttonClicked()">Mutate</button>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Output("parentFun") parentFun: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
....

buttonClicked() {
  this.parentFun.emit();
}
```

This is also working for me. With this approach I can do a lot more other changes as well. All my unit test cases are also passing on Jasmine and Karma.

Here's is a working demo: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5dhxcp)

Comment: create stacblitz for that

Comment: @BartoszTermena, Sure Sir, thank you for reminding. I've added it to the answer also. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5dhxcp

Answer (score 0):

[Share Data between components in Angular](https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/)

Check this out, the Child to Parent: Sharing Data via Output() and EventEmitter section

Answer (score 0):

Emiting an event using @output and EventEmitter from @angular/core in child component to parent, we can change/modify parent component value by triggering an event from child component.